# Search function by key in local database

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm working with a local database for the first time today and I ran into a problem. What I can't find by key is what I need, the function always returns null

Here is some data that might help you

1. Response from the server in json format -

```
    {
      "services": {
        "fg_0": {
          "ru": "IndianOil",
          "en": "IndianOil",
          "keywords": "",
          "id": "555",
          "sellTop": "78"
        },
        "vj_0": {
          "ru": "Stormgain",
          "en": "Stormgain",
          "keywords": "",
          "id": "412",
          "sellTop": "231"
        },
    "qd_0": {
          "ru": "Taobao",
          "en": "Taobao",
          "keywords": "таобоа",
          "id": "254",
          "sellTop": "254"
        }
      },
      "any_operator": {
        "any": {
          "ru": "Любой другой",
          "en": "Any other",
          "cn": ""
        }
      }
    }
```

2. How do I create a database -

   ```
     class DatabaseHelper {
     static final _databaseName = "translates.db";
     static final _tableName = "services";
     static final _columnRu = "ru";
     static final _columnEn = "en";
     static final _columnKeywords = "keywords";
     static final _columnId = "id";
     static final _columnSellTop = "sellTop";

     static Future<Database> _database() async {
       final path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), _databaseName);
       return openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (db, version) async {
         await db.execute('''
             CREATE TABLE $_tableName (
               $_columnId TEXT,
               $_columnRu TEXT,
               $_columnEn TEXT,
               $_columnKeywords TEXT,
               $_columnSellTop TEXT
             )
             ''');
       });
     }

     static Future<void> saveJsonToDb(Map<String, dynamic> jsonString) async {
       // final data = json.decode(jsonString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
       final db = await _database();
       final count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(
           await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM services'));
       print(count);
       print(count.runtimeType);
       if (count == 0) {
         await db.transaction((txn) async {
           for (final service in jsonString['services'].values) {
             await txn.insert(_tableName, {
               _columnId: service['id'],
               _columnRu: service['ru'],
               _columnEn: service['en'],
               _columnKeywords: service['keywords'],
               _columnSellTop: service['sellTop'],
             });
           }
         });
       }
     }

   }
   ```
3. Search function -

```
    static Future<String?> searchEnValue(String key) async {
        final db = await _database();
        final test = await db.query(_tableName);
        print(test);
        final result = await db.query(_tableName,
            columns: [_columnEn], where: '$_columnId = ?', whereArgs: [key]);
        if (result.isNotEmpty) {
          return result.first[_columnEn] as String;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
```

4. How do I call the function -

   ```
       final enValue = await DatabaseHelper.searchEnValue('fg_0');
       print(enValue); // null (IndianOil)
   ```

I need the key to be "vj_0", "fg_0" and so on, and that I search for them and get the "en" value